# Var java with data came from mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'll keep this into ex: test.js

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];
var days =['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday'];
```

I call the test.js with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
```

and at last the function :

```
<script>
```

**some function here bla bla bla .....**

```
$("#month").autocomplete(months, {});
$("#days").autocomplete(days, {});

</script>
```

next the html

```
<input type="text" id="month">
<input type="text" id="days">
```

I've done with that all and working very well.

The question is on test.js (top line) is there any way to change the array data in the test.js, with no change variables??

Where is the data take from a database table with php ??

Comment: `var months = <?php echo json_encode(array('January', 'February', ..)); ?>;` Where array would be something you got from a database. (ofcourse this would require the file to be test.php instead)

Comment: you mean, change the js file into a php file? from test.js in to test.php...Okay I will try it thank

Comment: awesome, now I have more than one autocomplete text with different table where data came from database, in the same form with only 1 function...thanks a lot @Anand